# Fake Trim/Cut with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, trim, exoplayer, cut

I would like to simulate trimming/cutting on a video with **ExoPlayer**.

For trimming I managed to find a solution, I'm using **ClippingMediaSource**, passing the start position and end position, so that I'm making a shorter play.

Is there any way to make it simulate the cut behaviour? (to exclude a part of the video from the result)

Comment: you could take a look at my library https://github.com/a914-gowtham/android-video-trimmer . the UI code of the library might help you

Comment: doesn't help...